# Need to get a count of users group by if all course activity is completed by date

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables users and user_activity, I need to get output, there are 3 users in users table, and in user_activity table all users have records in the table, for user_id = 1 have all 2 activity is completed, its both activity_status is 1 and there is mention on which date activity is completed, which is activity_completed, and for user_id = 2 only 1 activity is completed, for user_id = 3 all activity is completed what I need is if all the activity is completed for particular user then only we need to consider that user in record, I need to fetch data with activity_completed desc order, I need to count user date wise, but that date should have to consider the last date when the last course completed, here I have uploaded my all data detail

```
users table
```

[image]

```
user_activity table
```

[image]

I need its output like below

```
+-----------+-----------+
| date      | total     |
+-----------+-----------+
|2019-05-06 |      2    |
+-----------+-----------+
```

I tried below query which is not working for me

```
SELECT ua.activity_completed as date_by,counT(ua.activity_id) as total
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN user_activity as ua 
ON u.ID = ua.user_id 
WHERE ua.activity_completed IS NOT NULL AND ua.activity_completed !="0" AND ua.activity_completed >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
group by date_by having count(*)  = sum(case when ua.activity_status = 1 then 1 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using distinct ua.user_id

```
SELECT ua.activity_completed as date_by,count(distinct ua.user_id) as total
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN user_activity as ua 
ON u.ID = ua.user_id 
WHERE ua.activity_completed IS NOT NULL 
AND ua.activity_completed !="0" 
AND ua.activity_completed >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
group by date_by 
having count(*)  = sum(case when ua.activity_status = 1 then 1 end)
```

Comment: You need to read my question properly, that way you will get the output

Comment: your title is "Need to get a count of users group by if all course activity is completed by date" and i miised  the part related  to having clause  ..  because for the question i think is  marginal   .. if you want the number of user .. the count the user  ..anyway the having clause is added